# programmatic view transition in dojo mobile

Tags: dojo

I would like to perform a programmatic view transition.

Here is a code I've tried :

```
var v = registry.byId('myenergy-pane');
v.transitionTo("home-pane");
```

Here is another one

```
var v = registry.byId('myenergy-pane');
v.performTransition("home-pane",1,"slide",null);
```

None of them is working.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The second code you provided should work, but that's considering the following facts:

The code is executed after the DOM is loaded and the views are parsed by the `dojo/parser`. The correct way to indicate that is by using `dojo/ready`, for example:

```js
require(["dojo/ready"], function(ready) {
    var v = registry.byId('myenergy-pane');
    v.performTransition("home-pane", 1, "slide", null);
});
```

Both given IDs (`myenergy-pane` and `home-pane`) are related to a widget (not only a DOM node) and are both views (`dojox/mobile/View` or inheriting from).

Make sure you are loading `dijit/registry` and the `registry` module alias is actually mapped to the correct module.

I also made a JSFiddle to demonstrate that it should be working: http://jsfiddle.net/g00glen00b/3JMnC/